# After hosting my Nextjs website in vercel. When I tried To login with google it redirect me to localhost:3000

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I use supabase for backend

I am trying to login with google and it should't redirect me to localhost

Answer (score 0):

I got that answer. Open Supabase and go to auth under auth go to URL Configuration and setup your site url.